Как в Java считать сколько байтов в чарсете будет занимать мой String?
Как в Java считать сколько байтов занимает мой String например в US_ASCII? В C# есть Encoding.GetByteCount и это то что мне нужно, то есть мне нужна быстрая валидация в UI на длину байт и я не хочу создавать массив байтов а хочу считать без алокации памяти

Без аллокации памяти можно только в уме посчитать.

US_ASCII - однобайтовая. Число байт будет равно числу символов в строке. Если вы хотите узнать число байт в UTF8, то можно написать функцию, которая вычислит число байт. Это не сложно - четыре условия от кода символа (ещё обработка суррогатных пар, правда). Написать можно. Задайте вопрос более конкретно, сейчас это больше тема для болтовни, чем вопрос.

@RomanC к примеру валидация Wi-Fi пароля который может максимум занимать 63 октета попробуйте на смартфоне ввести ASCII символы и будет максимум 63 но если вводить какие-то китайские символы то их будет значительно меньше ну не создает же код ОС смартфона новый массив байтов всего String в UI каждый раз когда вы пишете следующий символ пароля

@Mik может и создаёт, почему бы и нет)

@RomanC String уже в памяти, я понимаю получать из него байты когда куда-то передать но не при валидации

@Mik, в какую конкретно кодировку вы переводите строку? Я не верю что иероглифы можно перевести в US_ASCII. Если у вас байты будут в UTF8, то это становится конкретной задачей, которую я знаю как решить. Вы не получите чёткого ответа без уточнения вопроса.

Пароль от вайфая подразумевает UTF-8, длину которого можно и руками посчитать (может, ОС смартфона так и считает) https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511490

CharsetEncoder может перекодировать строку в константной памяти и просто сосчитать байтики. Интересно?

вот это уже похоже на решение, меня просто немного смущает что C# имеет это на борту для всех кодировок а Java нет

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а разве CharsetEncoder не будет использовать дополнительный буфер, что будет вполне сравнимо с getBytes() вариантом?  Похожий способ Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(str).limit();, но нужно знать кодировку.

@NowhereMan, я собираюсь использовать буфер размером один байт. Видимо можно сделать решение, которое не будет выделять память во время работы. Только один раз до неё.

ByteCounter считает байты строки в указанной кодировке. Память выделяется при создании объекта. Сам подсчёт память не почти не выделяет.
Используется CharsetEncoder.encode. Входной буфер – один символ, выходной буфер – десять байт. Если encode пожалуется на переполнение выходного буфера, выделяется новый буфер, в два раза большего размера.
NB encode никогда не должен жаловаться на переполнение буфера, десяти байт должно хватить всем. В случае UTF-8 самая длинная последовательность байт - четыре. Большего количества на понадобится даже для эмодзи. Самая большая единица кодирования – суррогатная пара, а она всегда поместится в четыре байта.
В примере два экземпляра ByteCounter. Первый игнорирует ошибки кодирования, так же как это делает String.getBytes. Второй умеет замечать ошибки и бросает исключение.
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.CoderResult;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Charset cs = Charset.forName(args[0]);
        ByteCounter bc1 = new ByteCounter(cs.newEncoder()
            .onMalformedInput     (CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
            .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
        );
        ByteCounter bc2 = new ByteCounter(cs.newEncoder());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print(s.getBytes(cs).length);
            System.out.print(" ");
            try {
                System.out.print(bc1.countBytes(s));
            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                System.out.print("N/A");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            try {
                System.out.print(bc2.countBytes(s));
            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                System.out.print("N/A");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static class ByteCounter {
        private final CharsetEncoder ce;
        private final CharBuffer in = CharBuffer.allocate(1);
        private ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
        public ByteCounter(CharsetEncoder ce) {
            this.ce = ce;
        }
        public int countBytes(String s) throws CharacterCodingException {
            int bytes = 0;

            ce.reset();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                in.put(0, c);
                in.position(0);
                for (; ;) {
                    out.position(0);
                    CoderResult cr = ce.encode(in, out, false);
                    if (cr.isError()) {
                        cr.throwException();
                    }
                    bytes += out.position();
                    if (!cr.isOverflow()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    out = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 * out.capacity());
                }
            }
            return bytes;
        }
    }
}


$ javac Temp.java

$ java Temp US-ASCII << EOF
Hello!
Привет!
こんにちは！
你好！
EOF

6 6 6 Hello!
7 7 N/A Привет!
6 6 N/A こんにちは！
3 3 N/A 你好！


$ java Temp UTF-8 << EOF
Hello!
Привет!
こんにちは！
你好！
EOF

6 6 6 Hello!
13 13 13 Привет!
18 18 18 こんにちは！
9 9 9 你好！


P.P.S. Я обещал обойтись одним байтом и не смог. Если CharsetEncoder.encode сообщает о переполнении, ему требуется предоставить буфер большего размера. Отдавать закодированную строку по одному байту он отказывается. Так что сделан буфер в десять байт и добавлен механизм увеличения буфера при переполнении. Его можно протестировать, установив исходный размер буфера в единицу.

Интересный вариант.  Однобайтовым буфером всё-таки не обошлось )  А почему пришлось аллоцировать 10 байт в ByteBuffer out?

@NowhereMan, я могу сделать однобайтовый буфер. На спор. Но код станет сложнее: ещё один цикл и производительность упадёт: на обработку многобайтовых символов будет уходить несколько вызовов encode. Идеальное решение должно бы использовать два буфера: 256 символов входной и килобайт выходной. Тогда большинство строк будет обрабатываться в один вызов encode. А длинные строки уже потребуют нескольких вызовов. Буферизация. Но память всё равно константная.

@NowhereMan, 10 байт позволяют избежать цикла при записи байтов. Хватило бы и четырех.

@NowhereMan, дополнил ответ. Одним байтом обойтись нельзя. Десяти скорее всего хватит, но надо написать механизм удвоения размера выходного буфера в случае его переполнения. Проспорил.

Так спора не было как такового )) То есть минимум 1 символ во входном, 4 байта в выходном должно хватить для "обычных" символов, но какие-нибудь картинки/эмодзи могут представлять комбинации нескольких Unicode-символов

@StanislavVolodarskiy, для современного unicode (с его 21 битовыми кодами) максимальный размер символа в кодировке utf-8 это 4 байта. Вообще, если представить "максимальный" utf-8, то для символа в нем может потребоваться 7 байт (и так можно закодировать 36 бит). Значит 10 байт для буфера под utf-8 хватит "за глаза"

Да уж, NowareMan с его ссылкой на zero-width joiner показал, что я смотрю на мир слишком оптимистично

@avp, пример с джойнером не влияет на кодирование отдельных символов. На отображение влияет, а кодируются все части по отдельности. Так что четырёх байтов должно быть достаточно.
